How i start second process group after completion of frist process group in NIFI
I am new to NIFI , I have two process group i want to execuate process group first after completion of frist group successfully,process group second start (both group may be independent) but i want to process in a sequence
PG1>>SUCCESS>>PG2(start)
i have two process group CREATE_TEMP_TABLE and SELECT_AND_INSERT_TEMP_CR_RAW
